# Algorithm for determining whether $N=a^b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I have been working my way through Nielsen and Chuang's "[Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](http://www.johnboccio.com/research/quantum/notes/QC10th.pdf)" text, and I have gotten stuck on Exercise 5.17 (on pg. 234) as shown below.

[image: Exercise 5.17]

I have been able to complete part (1) by using logarithms, but am getting stuck on part (2) and therefore parts (3) and (4). For part (2), I do not understand where the $y$ comes from in the equation $x=y/b$, since $y$ is not mentioned previously. Can somebody tell me what $y$ means? Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that $y$ refers to the two closest $u_i$ that make the relation stated before.

Answer (score 2):

The text contains a simple but confusing typo there. It should read: "$y = \log_2 N$" instead of just saying $\log_2 N$. Thus $2^y = 2^{(xb)} = (2^x)^b = N$, i.e. $2^x$ is the exact value for $a$ calculated in floating number, and $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the integers that approximate $a$ from below and above. If either of $u_1^b$ or $u_2^b$ actually matches with $N$, then it means $a$ was actually an integer and the matching $u_1$ or $u_2$ is the value for $a$.

Comment: That makes sense, but then why does it say that it takes $O(L^2)$ operations in (2)? If you are computing $x=\log_2 N /b$ for each $b \leq L$, and then $2^x$ and $u_1$ and $u_2$, then you are doing $O(L)$ operations (in particular four for each $b \leq L$)

Comment: @MBolin Those steps aren't $O(1)$. What you call "four" operations have some complexity themselves. For example, just doing multiplication of two $L$ bit numbers would be $O(L^2)$ using the naive multiplication algorithm.